# PHP - Best practice to create a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a multidimensional array like below.

```
$my_array = array();

$a = 'foo';
$b = 'bar';
$c = 'baz';

$my_array[$a][$b][$c] = 'hello world';
```

Is this a best practice to create multidimensional arrays ? Do we need to initialize an empty array for every level and then insert a key like below ?

```
$my_array = array();

$a = 'foo';
$b = 'bar';
$c = 'baz';

$my_array[$a] = array();
$my_array[$a][$b] = array();
$my_array[$a][$b][$c] = 'hello world';
```

The first implementation just works fine. I just want to be aware if that is the right thing to follow and there won't be any issues/warnings in older PHP versions.

Edit: The variable keys are just hardcoded in this example. Ideally they would be dynamic.

Comment: "in older PHP versions" which version are you talking about?

Comment: must be an odd unmaintainable app, https://3v4l.org/FtjoT imo keys and structure should be concrete, there should be no reason to define variables for array keys like your doing

Comment: @LawrenceCherone The variable keys are dynamic and not hardcoded. I've hardcoded t just for an example. Ideally those variables will be a function parameter or something like that.

Comment: need a real example or show adding 3 different values, how do you access them if they are dynamic and changing?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone they variable keys come from a function parameter. My concern is do I need to do something like `if( !array_key_exists($a, $my_array) ){ $my_array[$a] = array(); }` and so on. I've stripped down to make the example simple.

Comment: No, PHP does NOT need you to do something like that, not even `PHP 5` (my answer is about maintainability, not PHP requirements).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your usage, for example, some frameworks may require you to provide an empty `array` instead of `null` (while others may require the opposite).

Although generally (for your own usage), doing `$my_array['a']['b'] = array();` is not required, I personally would still recommend doing initialization.

Consider following:

1. You have some rather big function.
2. You leave the code for few months, later once you read again, you wonder if the array has anything else???
3. You would be forced to read entire function (if you don't have initializer, like `$my_var['a']['b'] = array()`).